# Pyspark equivalent of na_filter = True when reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

i have a csv with 10 columns. every column has 'NA" values and are in string. so while import in pandas, i did

df = pd.read_csv(r'file_name.csv',na_filter=True)

i want to know the the pyspark equivalent of na_filter=True to change the "NA" values in string format to proper null values

Comment: see [spark doc on csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html). you can try to use the nullValue option.

Comment: df = spark.read.csv("file_name.csv", inferSchema = True, header = True)

how will you use that option in here?

Comment: the doc is very easy to read and understand how options are specified. in your case, `spark.read.option(<option property name as string>, <option property value as string>).csv(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from pyspark.sql import functions as funcs, SparkSession, Column, DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from typing import Any, List
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


def filter_na_values(df: SparkDataFrame, *patterns: str) -> SparkDataFrame:
    """Port of `na_filter` from `pandas.read_csv` to Pyspark RDD.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
        The dataframe to clean.
    patterns : str
        The null patterns.

    Returns
    -------
    pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
        The cleaned dataframe.
    """
    final_pattern = "|".join(
        f'({pattern if isinstance(pattern, str) else pattern.decode("utf8")})'
        for pattern in patterns
    )
    df = df.select(
        *[
            funcs.regexp_replace(column, final_pattern, "").alias(column)
            for column in df.columns
        ]
    )
    for column in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn(
            column,
            funcs.when(funcs.col(column) == "", None).otherwise(funcs.col(column)),
        )
    return df


def read_csv(path: str | List[str], **options: Dict[str, Any]) -> SparkDataFrame:
    """Read a CSV file into a Spark DataFrame.

    Parameters
    ----------
    path : str | List[str]
        Path to the CSV file.
    **options : dict
        Options to pass to the Spark DataFrameReader.

    Returns
    -------
    df : pyspark.sql.DataFrame
        Spark DataFrame containing the CSV data.
    """
    na_filter = options.pop('na_filter', True)
    extra_na_values = options.pop('na_values', [])
    df = spark.read.csv(path, **options)
    if na_filter:
        na_values = [
            b'NaN',
            b'1.#IND',
            b'-1.#QNAN',
            b'-nan',
            b'1.#QNAN',
            b'<NA>',
            b'n/a',
            b'-1.#IND',
            b'#N/A N/A',
            b'N/A',
            b'#NA',
            b'nan',
            b'-NaN',
            b'NULL',
            b'#N/A',
            b'NA',
            b'\?',
            'null',
            *extra_na_values
        ]
        return filter_na_values(df, *na_values)
    return df
```

#### Example:

```py
import pyspark.pandas as ps
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

ps.DataFrame(
    [[10, 'NA', '?', 'nan', ''],
     [20, 'NA', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
     [30, '?', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
     [None, '', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
     [22.2,'nan', 'a', 'b', 'c']]
).to_csv('data.csv', num_files=1)
```

`read_csv`, with `filter_na=True`:

```py
>>> read_csv('data.csv', inferSchema=True, header=True, na_filter=True).show()

+----+----+----+----+----+
|   0|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|10.0|null|null|null|null|
|20.0|null|   a|   b|   c|
|30.0|null|   a|   b|   c|
|null|null|   a|   b|   c|
|22.2|null|   a|   b|   c|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

`read_csv`, with `filter_na=False`:

```py
>>> read_csv('data.csv', inferSchema=True, header=True, na_filter=False).show()

+----+----+---+---+----+
|   0|   1|  2|  3|   4|
+----+----+---+---+----+
|10.0|  NA|  ?|nan|null|
|20.0|  NA|  a|  b|   c|
|30.0|   ?|  a|  b|   c|
|null|null|  a|  b|   c|
|22.2| nan|  a|  b|   c|
+----+----+---+---+----+
```